# SSIS - Export data from multiple SQL Sources to single excel file

Tags: excel, ssis

```
 I have a Control flow with three Data Flow Tasks.
```

Each of these Data flow tasks execute a Stored Procedure and export the data to the same excel file. They all work fine independently. 
     However when I connect the Data flow tasks to execute one after another, the first one executes and exports the data to excel and then the exported file excel opens. 
    This errors out the other Data Flow tasks.
    How do I prevent the excel file from opening after the first data flow task is complete?